# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from secure web service

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to create a PHP script that would send leads to a merchant using SOAP and xml but I'm having this error:

Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://tst.webservices.outsurance.co.za/SecureHost/Lead/LeadPostService.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://tst.webservices.outsurance.co.za/SecureHost/Lead/LeadPostService.svc?wsdl"

It seems that I cannot connect to the secure web service. They said that I should include a certificate so I included it but I'm still getting the same error. I've searched some solutions and most of them are suggesting to enable, openssl, fopen etc but all of them are already enabled on my server. Here's my code:

```
function sendRequest($url, $params)
{
    $request = curl_init($url); // initiate curl object
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params); // use HTTP POST to send form data
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response.
    $response = curl_exec($request); // execute curl post and store results in $post_response
    curl_close ($request); // close curl object
    return $response;
}


// Get Variables sent from websites
$uname = $_GET['un'];
$usname = $_GET['ul'];
$uphone = $_GET['up'];
$uemail = $_GET['ue'];
$testlive = $_GET['test'];
$aff_id = $_GET['af'];
$unique_id = $_GET['uid'];
$script = $_GET['script'];

// Convert URL and Name split
$rurl = 'http://'.$_GET['rurl'];

// Split Name if no surname entered
if (strlen($usname) > 0) {
    $firstname = $uname;
    $lastname = $usname; // I have a first and lastname
} else {
    list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(" ",$uname,2); // I only entered my firstname
}
// Determine phone number format
$phoneformat = strpos($uphone,'-');
if($phoneformat === false) {
 // string - NOT found in haystack
 $phonesubmit = $uphone; 
} else {
    $phone1 = substr($uphone,0,3);
    $phone2 = substr($uphone,4,3);
    $phone3 = substr($uphone,8,4);
    $phonesubmit = $phone1.$phone2.$phone3;
}
// Determine Live or Test
$testlive = strtolower($testlive);
switch ($testlive) {
    case "test":
        $debug = true; //Set this to 'false' to redirect users
        $outurl = 'https://tst.webservices.outsurance.co.za/SecureHost/Lead/LeadPostService.svc?wsdl'; // Set to TEST environment
        break;
    case "live":
        $debug = false;
        $outurl = 'https://webservices.outsurance.co.za/SecureHost/Lead/LeadPostService.svc?wsdl'; // Set to LIVE environment
        break;
}

// Set Variables
if($debug) echo("<pre>\n");
if($debug) echo("Form data complete\n");
if($debug) echo("Creating XML document\n");

$cert = "certificate.cer";
$client = new SoapClient($outurl, array('local_cert'=>file_get_contents($cert)));

$xml = new stdClass();
$xml->mode = 'LIVE';
$xml->title = '';
$xml->firstname = $firstname;
$xml->lastname = $lastname;
$xml->id = $unique_id;
$xml->homecode = '';
$xml->hometel = '';
$xml->workcode = '';
$xml->worktel = '';
$xml->mobile = $phonesubmit;
$xml->homecode = '';
$xml->email = $uemail;
$xml->comment = $script;
$xml->source = 'UPSTART';
$xml->notes = '';
$xml->language = 'E';
$xml->product = 'P';

$result = $client->SubmitAffiliateLead($xml);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: do you need a local to load that url? i was able to load it without a local cert

Comment: Their documentation said that a certificate is needed. But yes i can load the url too without the cert. It's just that when sending the parameters to the web service using soap, I get teh error above. :(

Comment: shouldn't `local_cert` be the file path instead of content?

Comment: I tried to get remove the file_get_contents() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am experiencing same such error - maikelsabido please post the answer if you have resolved it.

Comment: @maikelsabido have you resolved this issue, I am getting the same error